# SQl Removing Duplicate Values from Columns after De -Dup Data

Tags: sql

I have De-Dup the data and My new Table look like:

```
Item_F  Item_O  Page    Sale_F  Sale_O  Week    Year
5680    5680    7   260 1260    1   2015
5679    5679    6   250 1250    2   2014
5682    5682    9   189 1189    1   2016
34569   5679    6   400 1250    2   2014
5678    5678    5   200 1200    1   2014
5683    5683    10  167 1167    2   2016
5681    5681    8   290 1290    2   2015
34572   5681    8   550 1290    2   2015
```

I want only those Sales_O VAlues in where Item_O  Not equal to Item_F.

I dont want to delete rows

Comment: `where Item_O <> item_F`

Answer (score 0):

```
select Distinct(Sale_O)
from TableName
where Item_O <> Item_F
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I want the original table as it is without the duplicate values in Sale_o.   Also, while de-dup query is it possible to get rid off the  duplicate values in Sale_o  ? PLease post an example of de-duplicating SQL and removing the  duplicate values in any of the fact within the resultant table.

Comment: It might happen then for same value in `Sale_O` there will be more than one record whewe `Item_F <> Item_O`.